# Stop timer when changing page with page view and bottom navigation

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation, flutter-pageview

I use the `BottomNavigationBar` that switches between the display of 5 different pages. Changing the pages is done with the help of `PageController` together with the `PageView` widget.

[image]

Within the pages, there are timers that run when entering and exiting the page and pull data from the server every X time by using `Timer.periodic`.

Because of the use of `PageView`, the pages are built at the same time and all the timers are running, how can the timers be canceled when moving from page to page through each page by itself?

Answer (score 0):

you could listen to the `PageController` and stop the timer. Like this

```
pageController.addListener(() { 
      if(controller.page == 1){
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
```

Comment: I have bottom navigation bar and there is always minimum 5 pages in the controller, also, the timers is in the pages themself

Comment: Then, you should listen to this controller on each page.

Comment: @BHARATHT how ?